# IOS: Приложение перестало быть во весь экран

Tags: ios

Обновил XCode, запустил cd ios && pod install и после этого мое приложение перестало быть нормальным... Оно стало будто увеличенным и не во весь экран.
Приложение на react-native@0.68.2

Код, который поставил для теста:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { Dimensions, View, Text} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
  const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

  return (
    <View style={{ width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight, backgroundColor: "#fff" }}>
      <Text style={{color: "#000"}}>dfd</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел проблему.
Слетел Launch Screen File как-то сам, установил и все стало нормально
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]